# Boost documentation images not appearing

Tags: boost

I cannot view the images from boost.org documentation.

For example,

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/hyperexponential_dist.html

Looking at the source code and clicking the image links, I get "Error 404: File not found".

Apparently my professor can view the images no problem, but my classmates and I cannot. Does anyone know why I can't view any of the images on the boost.org documentation website? Thanks.

Comment: Please report the issue on the https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/

Comment: This question is about a bug in a website

Comment: @sehe I realize its not a coding question (and therefore off topic), but I'm sure it will help other people out.

Comment: I've added an issue for this (https://github.com/boostorg/website/issues/93). And next time you can do the same, as @sehe mentions.

Answer (score 3):

The [older 1.57.0 version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/hyperexponential_dist.html) is ok.

They changed their image format from PNG to SVG in v1.58.0, but these are not available on the site (the offline version contains the SVG files).